# Can this be achieved without using a table? Percentage height in dynamic container

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am at a loss! For the first time ever, I have found something that I believe cannot be achieved without using a table for layout.

I am trying to place a separator `div` inbetween unordered lists, that sizes its height automatically based on the size of the container.

1. I cannot use `height: x%;` because there is not a set height on the container as the content is dynamic!
2. I cannot use `position: absolute;top: 10px; bottom: 10px;` because the div must be placed relative to the unordered list!

Achieving this with a table would be very easy by simply manipulating the rows to give the same effect, however, as much of you will agree, tables are for the 1990's and I like to stay away from them unless absolutely necessary or if I am displaying tabular data.

I have recreated the problem in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3zk9/). There is a lot of code in this fiddle, most of which can be ignored. The `div`'s in question are part of a sub menu (Item 2 on the menu) and they have a class of 'separator', the styles of which can be found right at the end of the css.

Although all the code is in the jsFiddle, I have extracted the relevant snippets below:

**Note that I have temporarily fixed the height of the separator to 150px to make sure they are visible in the example**

HTML:

```
<li id="shiNav"><a href="#" title="#">Item 2</a>
    <div class="subMenuHandle horizontal-sprite">
        <div class="bg-noise"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="subMenu horizontal-sprite">
        <div class="bg-noise"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Menu Item 1</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Menu Item 2</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Menu Item 3</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Menu Item 4</strong></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Recently Opened File</li>
            <li><a href="#">File 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">File 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">File 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">File 20</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Most Used Customers</li>
            <li><a href="#">John Smith &amp; Co</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ManSys Limited</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sine Macula Limited</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Infralobo PLC</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lays PLC</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```css
/* Navigation */
#global-nav {position:absolute;width:460px;height:27px;left:15px;top:43px;}

#global-nav ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;}
#global-nav ul li {position:relative;display:block;width:92px;height:27px;float:left;padding:0;margin-left:8px;z-index:10;background-image:url("http://www.mansys.net/_test/sprite.png");background-position:-173px -32px;}
#global-nav ul li:hover {background-position:-173px -59px;}
#global-nav ul li:active {background-position:-173px -86px;}
#global-nav ul li a {display:block;width:92px;height:27px;line-height:27px;text-align:center;color:#fff;font-size:12px;text-shadow:#666 0 -1px 0;}
#global-nav ul li:hover a {color:#666;text-shadow:#fff 0 1px 0;}
#global-nav ul li:active a {color:#666;text-shadow:none;}

/* Set styles for specific navigation buttons */
#homNav {width:47px !important;margin-left:0 !important;margin-right:12px;background-position:-126px -32px !important;}
#homNav a {width:47px !important;}
#homNav:hover {background-position:-126px -59px !important;}
#homNav:active {background-position:-126px -86px !important;}

/* Set hovers of sub menu buttons to active images */
#masNav:hover,
#shiNav:hover,
#repNav:hover,
#setNav:hover
{background-position:-173px -86px !important;}

/* Set the sub menu handles */
#global-nav .subMenuHandle {position:relative;display:none;width:90px;height:12px;margin-top:-1px;border-left:1px solid #666;border-right:1px solid #666;z-index:1000;background-color:#fff;background-repeat:repeat-x;}

/* Set the sub menu container */
#global-nav .subMenu {position:relative;display:none;margin-top:-1px;width:870px;padding:10px 20px;border:1px solid #666;z-index:999;background-color:#ddd;background-position:0 -12px;background-repeat:repeat-x;overflow:hidden;clear:both;border-radius:3px;}

/* Set the menu hovers to show sub menus */
#global-nav ul li:hover .subMenuHandle,
#global-nav ul li:hover .subMenu
{display:block;}

/* Set the sub menu container positions */
#masNav .subMenu {margin-left:-83px;}
#shiNav .subMenu {margin-left:-183px;}
#repNav .subMenu {margin-left:-283px;}
#setNav .subMenu {margin-left:-383px;}

/* Set the noise in the menus */
.bg-noise {position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:url("https://www.mansys.net/_images/_global/bg-noise.png") repeat;}

/* Define sub menu Contents */
#global-nav .subMenu ul {display:block;float:left;overflow:hidden;}
#global-nav .subMenu ul li {display:inline;width:auto;height:25px;margin:0;float:none;background:none;}
#global-nav .subMenu ul li.title {line-height:25px;font-size:12px;color:#666;text-shadow:#fff 0 1px 0;text-align:left;}
#global-nav .subMenu ul li a {position:relative;display:block;width:auto;height:25px;line-height:25px;font-size:12px;color:#333;text-shadow:#fff 0 1px 0;text-align:left;z-index:1000;}

/* Define the sub menu separator */
#global-nav .subMenu .separator {position:relative;float:left;width:1px;background:#999;margin:20px 20px 0;height:90%}
```

Comment: I tried you're fiddle and % worked for me

Comment: @Mythril Sorry my mistake, I set the height of the container when I was testing and forgot to remove it. Please see new fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is achievable in modern browsers, however I don't have a device to hand to test any of the *Internet Explorers* of this world, and they will be the ones to watch out for *(they are notorious when it comes to position relative oddness or float problems)*.

Basically you need to rely on your menu container being `position:relative`, and then make sure you wrap your separators with a div that uses `float:left` to position the separator in the right locations (i.e. along the right side of your ul lists) - I've used `.psep`.

Once you do that you can use `position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0;` for your separator because it will calculate it's height in-regard to the first positioned parent (i.e. `#menu` not `.psep`) but calculate it's horizontal position in-regard to your ul lists.

Hope that makes sense? I put together an example below...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#menu {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu ul {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} 

.psep {
  float: left;
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sep { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
  width: 1px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>This is a test with a long title</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="psep"><div class="sep"></div></div>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>Another long text</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="psep"><div class="sep"></div></div>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just testing then will give feedback :-D Thank you

Comment: I would never have thought of using this method. You are a genius!!! Thank you so much!! It even works in IE7+!! Thank you! :-D

Comment: Thanks and no worries *at all*, that's what stackexchange is for - catching all the things the world might never have thought of - am glad it helped :)